# Android UI - rounded table with border 

Tags: android, user-interface

Can anyone help me on how i can achieve this style for android ?

[image]

I have not done much user interface designing in android. Can i use a TableLayout itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save this xml file in your drawable folder and use it in background of your table layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners 
    android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
    android:topRightRadius="6dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="6dp" />

<solid
    android:color="#ffffff"/>

<padding
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp"/>

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#c7c7c7" />

</shape>
```

You can change the border color and solid color as per your requirement.

**Note:** For details description of the above code please refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape).

Comment: yea, this gives me the shape. thanks a lot. for those lines in between i will have to use only table cells and make border for it right....

Answer (score 0):

You can use html instead and show data in webview.

I have done similar kind of work.